# How to select Closest distance from each category

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to get the closest locations in each category.  Can anyone help me do this?

```
var xml = new XElement("Locations", 
                    locations.OrderBy(n => n.CategoryID)
                        .ThenBy(n => distance(lat, lon, (double)n.Latitude, (double)n.Longitude))
                        .Where(n => (distance(lat, lon, (double)n.Latitude, (double)n.Longitude) <= 5))
                        .Select(location => 
                        new XElement("Location",
                            new XAttribute("CategoryID", location.CategoryID),
                            new XElement("Category", location.Category),
                            new XElement("LocationID", location.LocationID),
                            new XElement("LocationName", location.LocationName),
                            new XElement("Latitude", location.Latitude),
                            new XElement("Longitude", location.Longitude),
                            new XElement("Distance", distance(lat, lon, (double)location.Latitude, (double)location.Longitude)),
                            new XElement("Status", (location.HasManagedHours ? "Managed Hours" : "Open"))
                            )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but I'd suggest grouping is the way to go, something like:

```
var xml = new XElement("Locations",                             
  locations
    .GroupBy(n => n.CategoryID)
    .SelectMany(g => g
       .OrderBy(n => distance(lat, lon, (double)n.Latitude, (double)n.Longitude))
       .Take(1))
    .Select(location => 
      new XElement("Location",
          new XAttribute("CategoryID", location.CategoryID),
          new XElement("Category", location.Category),
          new XElement("LocationID", location.LocationID),
          new XElement("LocationName", location.LocationName),
          new XElement("Latitude", location.Latitude),
          new XElement("Longitude", location.Longitude),
          new XElement("Distance", distance(lat, lon, (double)location.Latitude, (double)location.Longitude)),
          new XElement("Status", (location.HasManagedHours ? "Managed Hours" : "Open"))
          )));
```

See [Projection Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx#standardqueryops_topic4) and [Grouping Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx#standardqueryops_topic9) for more info.

Comment: So the first select is just selecting the top one, and the second select is creating the elements and returning those?  Can you do two selects like that, I have never tried?

Comment: .First is  asking for a boolean value

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense.  I should have known what you meant

Comment: Just tested it out and needed to switch first Select to SelectMany so updated again.

Comment: Thanks i was wondering why it was throwing errors on the second select.  This looks great.